# SOQL- Writing query with multiple LastModifiedDate filters

Tags: soql, help

new to SOQL.
I am trying to write a query to retrieve a list of Ids from a few objects filtering each by their LastModifiedDate. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
Id 
from Object1

where (lastModifiedDate >=  2023-12-31T19:25:22.670972Z AND lastModifiedDate <=  2024-01-05T19:25:22.670972Z) AND 
 (Object2__r.LastModifiedDate >=  2023-12-31T19:25:22.670972Z AND Object2__r.lastModifiedDate <=  2024-01-05T19:25:22.670972Z) AND 
 (Object3__r.LastModifiedDate >=  2023-12-31T19:25:22.670972Z AND Object3__r.lastModifiedDate <=  2024-01-05T19:25:22.670972Z) AND 
 (Object4__r.LastModifiedDate >=  2023-12-31T19:25:22.670972Z AND Object4__r.lastModifiedDate <=  2024-01-05T19:25:22.670972Z) AND 
 (Object5__r.LastModifiedDate >=  2023-12-31T19:25:22.670972Z AND Object5__r.lastModifiedDate <=  2024-01-05T19:25:22.670972Z) AND 
 (Object6__r.LastModifiedDate >=  2023-12-31T19:25:22.670972Z AND Object6__r.lastModifiedDate <=  2024-01-05T19:25:22.670972Z) AND 
 (Object7__r.Object1__r.LastModifiedDate  >=  2023-12-31T19:25:22.670972Z AND Object7__r.Object1__r.lastModifiedDate <=  2024-01-05T19:25:22.670972Z) AND 
 (Object7__r.Object2__r.LastModifiedDate  >=  2023-12-31T19:25:22.670972Z AND Object7__r.Object2__r.lastModifiedDate <=  2024-01-05T19:25:22.670972Z)
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working, please let me know if there is anything I can do.

Comment: What, precisely, does "not working" mean? Is it not returning rows, or are you getting an error message? If you are getting an error, you should copy/paste the error verbatim. You can [edit] your question to add more details.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with this query? Also, you're missing the SELECT keyword.

Comment: @DevelBase2 The SELECT thing was just from some mis-formatting

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to include more detail and clarify, especially the specific relationships between all these objects, and what specifically is "not working."  Are you getting an error?  Please [edit] your post.